# admob changed publisher-id's?

Tags: air, admob

So i was told today that the admob publish ids changed format.

Is this true?

I see my ad is no longer working in AIR,

Example of the change:

a1f2d4637cd4b0f

to

ca-app-pub-2123237899511231/6221231845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Admob pusher ids are being replaced with AdUnitIds in the new Admob dashboard. But old publisher ids continue to work.